# How to change properties of a div that were initially set by timelineMax?

Tags: javascript, css, gsap

On site landing page i made animations using timelineMax which sets height and width of a div.

```
const tl = new TimelineMax();
tl.fromTo(welcomeDiv, 1, {height: '0%'}, {height: '80vh'})
.fromTo(welcomeDiv, 1.2, {width: '100%'}, {width: '80%'})
```

Found out that i can't change these properties when my window resizes neither using media queries or div.style.height/width property in js. Other properties set only in css not affected.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    #welcomeDiv{
       height: 160vh; // doesn't work
       background-color: yellow; // works
    }
```

Comment: TimelineMax is from the old version of GSAP. We highly recommend [using GSAP 3 instead](https://greensock.com/3-migration).

Answer (score 1):

Try by adding [!important](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```
height: 160vh !important;
background-color: yellow !important;
```

Comment: It works, would have never figured out myself. Thanks !

Comment: @Zobla happy to help